# which minification module to use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify

I need to minify my JavaScript and CSS files and I see that there are many modules available for minifying JavaScript.

- **node-minify** - https://github.com/srod/node-minify
- **minifyjs** - https://github.com/clarkf/minifyjs
- **node-jsmin** - https://github.com/pkrumins/node-jsmin

There may be some more, which I do not know at the moment.
need some advice as to which one I can use for minification of both JavaScript and CSS files.

Comment: Also checkout `uglify` library.

Comment: Thanks for all the four answers. I have seen rave reviews for uglify.js and I see that both minj and minifyjs uses uglify internally.. So thinking of going ahead with one of them. Again node-jsmin also seems to be a good option as it is based on Douglas Crockford's algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/).

Comment: ...with advanced optimizations :)

Answer (score 2):

I use http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/ for both css and js and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://prettydiff.com/fulljsmin.js because this modified version of JSMin supports minification for CSS and adds automatic semicolon insertion for JavaScript.  Its one file, its portable, and its fast.

You can test it out at http://prettydiff.com/